# Unreferenced assemblies are not being published to IIS using WebDeploy

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-6.0, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.3.0) to publish an ASPNET (NET6) webapp to IIS.

I use a plugin system for some of the assemblies and these are not referenced in the main project. I need these assemblies published, so I added the following post-build events:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)pathtoassembly\bin\Debug\net6.0\assemblyname.dll" "$(TargetDir)" /Y
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)pathtoassembly\bin\Debug\net6.0\assemblyname.pdb" "$(TargetDir)" /Y
```

I do the above for a number of assemblies. But a couple of these are not being published. The build process does copy the files into the main project's `bin` folder.

The temporary publish folder (`\obj\Debug\net6.0\win-x64\PubTmp\Out`) does not contain these files so therefore they are not being published. All other unreferenced assemblies which I copy in the post-build event are successfully being published.

Is there a reason certain files do not get published?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the following in the publish profile file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JobFiles Include="**\Plugins*">
    <Path>\Plugins</Path>
  </JobFiles>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(JobFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

After adding the above, publishing works as expected.